# run using KLEE error

Tags: klee

I am new to Klee, so I started to make the tutorials.

If for compilation I use:

1. llvm-gcc --emit-llvm -c -g get_sign.c   and then I try to run using   klee get_sign.o   I get the error :    KLEE: ERROR: error loading program 'get_sign.o': Invalid MODULE_CODE_GLOBALVAR record    . The error is defined in the BitcodeReader.cpp file   http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/BitcodeReader_8cpp_source.html    at line 01594.
2. clang (that I have used succesfully for my LLVM passes), it appears that is not possible to use it:     KLEE: ERROR: error loading program 'get_sign.o': Invalid bitcode signature   .

Do you know what I can do?

Also, it would be nice to give Klee inputs compiled with Clang that I already use for my passes, but as the error suggest, it is possible?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I installed Klee over LLVM 3.1. In the instructions from http://klee.llvm.org/GetStarted.html it is mentioned that Klee is fully compatible with LLVM 2.9. It is mentioned : "KLEE is currently tested only on Linux x86-32 and x86-64 targets, using LLVM 2.9. KLEE will not work with older LLVM versions (e.g., 2.5), and might not work with newer versions (e.g., 3.0).". 
I installed Klee on LLVM 2.9 and it is working perfectly.